# Unable to locate an uploaded file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to download an uploaded file but I am unable to locate the file. I am giving correct path but its not downloading the file. Sharing my code of uploading and downloading of file. Kindly tell me the corrections.

Uploading file code.

```php
$filename = $rep->getClientOriginalName();
$fileSize = $rep->getClientSize();
$rep->storeAs('/reportAttachment/',$filename);
$reportId = Report::where('reportId',$request->reportId)->first();
$reportA = new ReportAttachment;
$reportA->reportAttachmentFile = $filename;
$reportA->report_id = $reportId->id;
$reportA->save();
```

Downloading file code

```php
<a href="/reportAttachment/{{$at->reportAttachmentFile}}" download="{{$at->reportAttachmentFile}}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download">
            Download
        </i>
    </button>
</a>
```

This is my code kindly tell me my mistake.

Comment: Unless `yoursite/reportAttachment` points to a location in your `public` folder, or is `symlinked` appropriately, you're gonna get a `404` on that URL. Have a look at the documentation for the recommended way to handle this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#file-uploads

Comment: you will have to give us what error message you see, and probably you might want to check the storage folder to confirm whether the file is stored or not

Comment: @TimLewis I have tried the one given in document too but my files are being uploaded in storage/app/reportAttachment folder what can I do to correct it

Comment: @ShobiPP my files are being stored in storage/app/reportAttachment folder

Comment: That's correct, you then run `php artisan storage:link`, which `symlinks` `public/storage` to `stroage/app`, so a URL of `storage/reportAttachment/{{$at->reportAttachmentFile}}` should now be valid. (note the `storage` added before `reportAttachment`)

Comment: @TimLewis what if I have a folder in public folder in which there are another files which are being uploaded will those files be accessible after running this command4

Comment: Of course; `php artisan storage:link` creates a folder in public called `storage`, which is `symlinked` to `storage/app`. Any existing folders in public aren't touched, and are still accessible as `yoursite/{folder}` (assuming your `.htaccess` file/server settings have the root of your site as the `public` folder)

Comment: @TimLewis still my file is unable to download

Comment: Navigate to `yoursite/storage`; do you see a directory listing, or do you get a `RouteNotFoundException`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171576/discussion-between-nida-akram-and-tim-lewis).

Answer (score 1):

The default configuration is for your root directory not to be publicly accessible. You should either create symlinks, build a view for relaying private assets to public addresses, or more simply store your files in a public folder:

Change

`$rep->storeAs('/reportAttachment/',$filename);` to

`$rep->storeAs('public/reportAttachment/',$filename);`

Then change

`<a href="/reportAttachment/{{$at->reportAttachmentFile}}"...` to

`<a href="{{ asset("reportAttachment/".$at->reportAttachmentFile) }}"...`

Note this approach would make all `reportAttchments` available to all users, so if the files are sensitive you should create an authenticated view to relay files from your private storage to the public. Comment if that's what you mean.